# Array to pointer class template argument deduction works for template guide, but not for non template version, is that correct or bug?

Tags: c++, c++17, template-argument-deduction

I have class template with single type param and `const char*` type full specialization, simplified example below:

```
template <typename T>
struct PrettyPrint {
    PrettyPrint(const T& value) : value(value) {}
    const T& value;
    friend std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& os, const PrettyPrint& pp) {
        return os << "(" << pp.value << ")";
    }
};
template <>
struct PrettyPrint<const char*> {
    PrettyPrint(const char* value) : value(value) {}
    const char* value;
    friend std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& os, const PrettyPrint& pp) {
        return os << "\"" << pp.value << "\"";
    }
};
```

In short - to print char strings like `"abc"` and all other values like `(123)` (`""` vs `()`)

So, I added, as a replacement of additional partial specialization for all `char[N]` types  a deduction guide:

```
template <std::size_t N>
PrettyPrint(char(&)[N]) -> PrettyPrint<const char*>; //deduction guide
```

Unfortunately it does not work:

```
 std::cout << PrettyPrint(7) << PrettyPrint("aaa") << PrettyPrint((const char*)"bbb");
```

> (7)(aaa)"bbb"

Expected output:

> (7)"aaa""bbb"

But, surprisingly, this works:

```
template <typename T, std::size_t N>
PrettyPrinter(T(&)[N]) -> PrettyPrinter<const T*>; //deduction guide

 std::cout << PrettyPrint(7) << PrettyPrint("aaa") << PrettyPrint((const char*)"bbb");
```

> (7)"aaa""bbb"

So the questions:

1. Is that correct (then why) or this is a bug in compilers (tested with gcc/clang - newest versions)
2. If that is correct - then how to limit this template deduction guide to `char` only?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is expected. A string literal has type `const char[N]`. Note the `const`. A const value cannot bind to a non-const reference, so your deduction guide is effectively not chosen and the primary template gets instantiated instead.

```
template <std::size_t N>
PrettyPrint(const char(&)[N]) -> PrettyPrint<const char*>;
```

Your second deduction guide works because here, `T` is deduced to be `const char`, which is perfectly fine.

Answer (score 8):

The issue here is a string literal is a `const char[N]`, not a `char[N]`.  Changing the guide to

```
template <std::size_t N>
PrettyPrint(const char(&)[N]) -> PrettyPrint<const char*>; //deduction guide
```

will give you the expected results.

Comment: It works, Just to explain myself - I checked with this trick `template <typename T> class WhatIsT;  WhatIsT<decltype(PrettyPrint("aa"))>  dummy;`  and it gives me "implicit instantiation of undefined template 'WhatIsT<PrettyPrint<char [3]> >'"  - note `char[3]` - not `const char[3]`) ... so I tried `char[N]` ... Thanks.

Comment: @PiotrNycz That's because your constructor takes a `const T&`, there is no need to deduce the `const` because it's already there :D

Comment: @Rakete1111 Do you think shall I use `T&&` instead in my general template version like `PrettyPrint(T&& value) : value(std::forward<T>(value)) {}  T&& value; ` . It works - but I am not sure here.

Comment: @PiotrNycz Can't say. I also don't see a difference between the two, so I'd say whatever you want :)